# CheckBox with custom appearance in .net MAUI

Tags: .net, checkbox, maui

I would like to use the functionality of the CheckBox control, and replace its appearance with vector paths like this one:

```
<controls:PathGeometry x:Key="IconMouseOver" Figures="M4 8v48h16v-16h16v16h16V32H20v16H4V8z M24 40V16h8v24h-8z"/>
```

Now, for each visual state of the CheckBox (checked/unchecked) in combination with mouseover / no mouseover, I have such a path.

I tried to derive from CheckBox, but I cannot find a mouseover event in CheckBox.

What can i do? Is this even the proper way to create a CheckBox with custom appearance?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I highly recommend checking out the CheckBox control from my library I have created it with SkiaSharp and it is as customizable as you can possibly think of https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls, have any recommendations? Feel free to add a feature request :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with SkiaSharp.

First step: derived a base control class from SKCanvasView:

```
using SkiaSharp.Views.Maui;
using SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.Controls;

namespace somenamespace;

public class CustomControlBase : SKCanvasView
{
    protected bool Hover;
    protected bool Hold;

    public CustomControlBase() => EnableTouchEvents = true;

    protected override void OnTouch(SKTouchEventArgs _e)
    {
        base.OnTouch(_e);

        if (_e.ActionType == SKTouchAction.Pressed) Hold = true;
        else if (_e.ActionType == SKTouchAction.Released) Hold = false;
        else if (_e.ActionType == SKTouchAction.Entered) Hover = true;
        else if (_e.ActionType == SKTouchAction.Exited) Hover = false;

        _e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Then derived from it a class with CheckBox functionality:

```
public class CustomCheckBox : CustomControlBase
  {
        public static readonly BindableProperty IsCheckedProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                nameof(IsChecked), typeof(bool), typeof(CustomCheckBox), false, BindingMode.TwoWay,
                propertyChanged: OnIsCheckedChanged);
    
        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get => (bool)GetValue(IsCheckedProperty);
            set => SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value);
        }
    
        protected override void OnTouch(SKTouchEventArgs _e)
        {
            base.OnTouch(_e);
            if (_e.ActionType == SKTouchAction.Released) IsChecked = !IsChecked;
            InvalidateSurface();
            _e.Handled = true;
        }
    
        // Here my custom appearance of the control, just for completeness
        protected override void OnPaintSurface(SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs _e)
        {
            base.OnPaintSurface(_e);
    
            Debug.WriteLine(Hold + " " + IsChecked + " " + Hover);
    
            var pathVisualization = PathVisualization.FromSymbolAndState(UiSymbol.Speaker, VisualState);
    
            var width = _e.Info.Width;
            var height = _e.Info.Height;
            float pathSize = 48;
            float padding = 0;
    
            float scaleFactor = Math.Min((width - 2 * padding) / pathSize, (height - 2 * padding) / pathSize); // Calculate the scaling factor
    
            var canvas = _e.Surface.Canvas;
            canvas.Clear(pathVisualization.BackColor.ToSKColor());
            canvas.Translate((width - pathSize * scaleFactor) / 2, (height - pathSize * scaleFactor) / 2); // Center the paths within the control
            canvas.Translate(padding, padding); // Apply padding
            canvas.Scale(scaleFactor); // Scale the paths
    
            using var paint = new SKPaint { Color = pathVisualization.ForeColor.ToSKColor(), IsAntialias = true, Style = SKPaintStyle.Fill, StrokeWidth = 1 };
            foreach (var pathString in pathVisualization.PathStrings)
            {
                using var path = SKPath.ParseSvgPathData(pathString);
                canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you just want to develop for the windows platform? There is no mouse for the android and ios but touch event.

For the windows platform, you can add the PointEntered event to the checkbox, this event will be triggered when the mouse is over it. And the PointExited event will be triggered when the mouse is not over it. Such as:

Use the control in the xaml:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="checkbox"/>
```

In the code behind:

```
    protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
    {
            
        base.OnHandlerChanged();
#if WINDOWS
            var platformview = checkbox.Handler.PlatformView as Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.CheckBox;
            platformview.PointerEntered += (s, e) =>
            {
                  // set value when mouse is over
            };
            platformview.PointerExited += (s, e) =>
            {
                  // set value when mouse is not over
            };
#endif
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought of this, too, but then I saw SkiaSharp, with which I do not have to program against every intended OS (Windows, Android, Apple)

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to know your problem is resolved. Happy coding!